# c++ while loop condition isn't playing nice with stack.empty()

Tags: c++, while-loop, stack

So I'm flustered by this bit of code - can't understand why it's misbehaving. The only thing I can think of is that stack.empty() isn't working properly with the while loop, but that seems ridiculous. You'll see in the output following the code that the program never makes it out of the while loop before the run fails.

declaration of opStack and newOrder:

```
queue<string> newOrder;
stack< vector<char> > opStack;
```

other stuff happens, then this code executes:

```
while(opStack.empty()==false){
    if(opStack.top()[1] != 'L'){
        cout<<"is stack empty?:"<<opStack.empty()<<endl;
        symbol = opStack.top()[0];
        newOrder.push(symbol);
        opStack.pop();
        cout<<"popped stack;"<<endl;
        cout<<"is stack empty?:"<<opStack.empty()<<endl;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
cout<<"made it out of while loop";
```

output:

```
is stack empty?:0
popped stack;
is stack empty?:1
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)
```

Comment: What is `opStack`? Is it an `std::stack` object?

Comment: @EitanT yeah, updated my question to show its declaration

Comment: Check also for `opStack.top().empty()`.

Comment: Try adding `<<endl` after the last `cout`, maybe it isn't getting flushed.

Comment: On the second iteration the stack is empty, and then you are trying to use top().

Comment: @interjay - that was the problem. the while loop was fine, and the real issue is in the line after the last cout. Put up an answer so I can accept it =).

Comment: @Wadsworth If you solve your own problem, it's best to put up the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @Wadsworth Since this question doesn't include the code that caused the problem, there is nothing of value to future users here. Please consider deleting the question.

Comment: @jogojapan; I agree that in it's current form the question doesn't add much, but the a valuable nugget in it for me, and possibly for other users, was that my code was good, but that the way I was using output for debugging was wrong. Should I repost and reformat the question to make that more evident, or should I just leave it alone in it's closed state? (and is that the same as deletion or do I need to do something else on my end?)

Comment: @Wadsworth It seems the question has been closed as "not a real question" meanwhile. Sorry for that; I am pretty sure I voted to close as "too localized", not as "not a real question". Re your question: Of course I don't know what happens in the line after the last `cout`. If there is something interesting going on there that is indeed not covered by other questions and can be stated in a clear and understandable way, it may make sense to open a new question and answer it yourself. Re-using the existing question might be confusing, because there are so many comments already.

Comment: @jogojapan Thanks for the tip. I created a new question and answer. If anybody stumbles across this old question and is still confused, there's a better question/answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185457/c-while-loop-doesnt-exit-on-false-condition/13185458#13185458