# c++ while loop doesn't exit on false condition

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements, stack

I'm having a problem in my code that results in a run time error. To debug the code I've thrown in some cout statements to find the last location that code executes properly. Based on the output it looks like the while statement breaks when the while condition evaluates to false, but I can't see how that's possible. Here's the code:

var declarations:

```
queue<string> newOrder;
stack< vector<char> > opStack;
char symbol;
```

stuff happens that populates the stack and queue, then this code is reached:

```
while(opStack.empty()==false){
    if(opStack.top()[1] != 'L'){
        cout<<"is stack empty?:"<<opStack.empty()<<endl;
        symbol = opStack.top()[0];
        newOrder.push(symbol);
        opStack.pop();
        cout<<"popped stack;"<<endl;
        cout<<"is stack empty?:"<<opStack.empty()<<endl;
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
cout<<"made it out of while loop";

if(opStack.top()[1] == 'L'){    
   opStack.pop();
}
else{
   errorEncountered = true;
}
```

this is the output:

```
is stack empty?:0
popped stack;
is stack empty?:1
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)
```

So, based on the output, the stack is empty at the end of the loop. This should makes the while loop condition false, but the program fails before the while loop exits. How can that be possible? Does it have something to do with the way that stacks work?

Comment: @casperOne Hey, please don't take offence, but I'm learning the ropes here and I'm not certain why you think my question "isn't real." The question, that I hunted for for several hours before posting was "why won't my while loop exit when it evaluates to false" there was nobody on the web who said, "take another glance at how you're debugging; specifically look at how you're generating your output" which was really the answer that I was looking for. - what's "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical" about that and why can it "not be reasonably answered in it's current form?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while loop DOES exit on the false condition. I wasn't debugging properly, and that made me focus on the wrong part of the code.

The problem is actually what happens AFTER the last cout. The statement after that, `if(opStack.top()[1] == 'L'){`, tries to get the top item from the empty stack and causes the run to fail.

But how is that possible, since we never see "made it out of while loop" in the output? It's because the last cout isn't ever flushed to the output before the program crashes. I added `<<endl` to the last cout, and that did the trick. "made it out of while loop" was displayed and I was able to pinpoint the real problem in the program. (solved it by putting the last if-else statement inside `if(opStack.empty()==false){//second if-else set}`)

Thanks to @interjay for pointing out that cout wasn't getting flushed in my original but poorly formatted question: [c++ while loop condition isn't playing nice with stack.empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131803/c-while-loop-condition-isnt-playing-nice-with-stack-empty#comment17894957_13131803))

Comment: Sir, this stymied me for a couple of days. Very glad you found the answer.

Comment: So am I. It was a complete aggravation for a few days for me too. Thank goodness for the good folks at stack overflow :)

Comment: And the lesson is to always use `cerr` for debugging because it's not buffered!

Comment: (unless you have a logging library that takes care of the flushing, of course)

Comment: I'm a little more curious about how you weren't "debugging properly".  I think *that* might be most helpful to others in the future, because debugging seems to be something rather difficult to teach (or learn, which is really the same thing).

Comment: @Michael Burr & others - What I meant by that is that because I didn't understand that my output was in limbo I couldn't focus on the part of the program that was actually causing problems. By including endl and forcing the output to flush I was able to determine the true nature of the problem.

Comment: @Jan Hudec would you expand on that about the logging library? Is there an example you can give me?

Comment: @Wadsworth: You can use a generic one (this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084052/c-logging-library-recommendation) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692238/better-logging-library-for-c) question), some frameworks (like Qt) have one or you can write some simple wrapper yourself. The wrapper usually creates temporary that returns ostream to write the message to and flushes the output in it's destructor (and takes care of locking or using temporary buffer and adding timestamp and such).